# Read data from multiple tables and evaluate results and generate report

Tags: hadoop, db2

I have some question regarding the effective way of reading values in DB and generating report.
I use hadoop to see data from multiple tables and do data analysis based on the results. 
I want to know if there is effective tool or way which can read data from multiple tables and evaluate if the values of certain columns are same across tables and send report if they are not same... I have 2 options, either I can read data from hadoop or I can connect to DB in DB2 and do it. Without creating a new java program, is there a tool which helps for the same? Like Talend tool which reads XML and writes output in DB ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Talend for this. Using Talend, you can read data from Hadoop as well as from database. In between you can perform your operation after fetching data and generate report.

Answer (score 0):

if your using alot of data, and do this sort of function alot elasticsearch is also a great help in this area. use ELK stack. although you would not need the 'L' logstash part of this necessarily